# MethodExpression IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: jsf-2

I've got a JSF page that is rendered dynamically - all components are created by the backing bean and added to a grid. I have a command button that I've created a MethodExpression to set the method to call when the button is clicked. But clicking the button results in the exceptions "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments" and "javax.faces.FacesException: wrong number of arguments".

The code that creates the button is

```
HtmlCommandButton addBtn1 = (HtmlCommandButton) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
getApplication().createComponent(HtmlCommandButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);
addBtn1.setId("addBtn1");
addBtn1.setValue("Add Row");
String addBtn1Action = "#{dynamicComponentTest.addBtn1_action}";
Class[] args = new Class[]{ActionEvent.class};
MethodExpression addBtn1ME = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().
getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), addBtn1Action, null, args);
addBtn1.setActionExpression(addBtn1ME);
mainGrid.getChildren().add(addBtn1);
```

Then the action method's signature is

```
public String addBtn1_action(ActionEvent event)
```

When I run my test app and click the button, I get the exceptions. However, if I change the signature to

```
public String addBtn1_action(ActionEvent[] event)
```

I get a MethodNotFoundException where it can't find "...DynamicComponentTest@1db3b45.addBtn1_action(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)"

Has anyone succesfully solved this issue? I have tried both null and String.class as the type of the return value in the createMethodExpression and that doesn't help solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action method should not have parameters. `ActionEvent` parameter is for `actionListeners`. So, remove that parameter, and change `createMethodExpression` call according to that. Also, return type of your action method is `String`. Third parameter of `createMethodExpression` is return type. You should put `String.class` in place of `null`. Finally:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().
        createMethodExpression(
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(),
          addBtn1Action, String.class, new Class[0]);
```

And action method signature:

```
public String addBtn1_action() {
    // ...
}
```